# About Radon-Nikodym theorem

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus

The theorem is as follows:
If $Q<<P$, then there exists a random variable $\Lambda$, such that $\Lambda\geq 0$, $E_P(\Lambda)=1$, and:

$$Q(A)=E_P(\Lambda I(A))=\int_A\Lambda dP.$$

According to my book from that line it follows that $E_Q(X)=E_P(\Lambda X)$. Can someone explain this implication in an elementary way (I'm quite new to Lebesgue integrals and such)?

From my understanding we have that:
$$E_Q(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}X(\omega)dQ(\omega),$$
and
$$E_P(\Lambda X)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Lambda(\omega)X(\omega)dP(\omega)$$
But how can i connect those expressions?
(This is btw why they also call $\Lambda=\frac{dQ}{dP}$, and looking at these two expression it makes sense...So I want to know the connection)

Comment: Heuristically, $dQ(\omega)=\Lambda(\omega)\,dP(\omega)$. A usual proof first shows it for *step functions* (discrete variables), then applies a monotone increasing limit argument separately to the positive and negative parts of $X$.